# augmented chain complex

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

From Hatcher's Algebraic Topology,

I know that a continuous map induces a morphism of chain complexes 
$f :C(X) → C(Y)$ by invariance of homotopy, but how would I show that $f$ also induces a morphism of augmented chain complexes?

Comment: invariance of homotopy is not the reason why a continous map induces a morphism of chain complexes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a map of chain complexes of abelian groups means having homomorphisms such that everything in the following diagram commutes:

$$
\begin{array}{c}
\cdots & \to & C_1(X)& \to& C_0(X) &\to  &0& \cdots \\
&&\downarrow&&\downarrow&&\downarrow \\
\cdots & \to & C_1(Y)& \to& C_0(Y)& \to  &0 &\cdots 
\end{array}
$$

Now for the augmentation just go ahead, take the same maps with a slight modification as follows:

$$
\begin{array}{c}
\cdots & \to & C_1(X)& \to& C_0(X) & \stackrel \epsilon \to  &\mathbb Z& \cdots \\
&&\downarrow&&\downarrow&&\downarrow \\
\cdots & \to & C_1(Y)& \to& C_0(Y)& \stackrel \epsilon \to  &\mathbb Z &\cdots 
\end{array}
$$

where you take the identity on the integers and the augmentaion map $\epsilon$. Everything will commute since $\epsilon= \epsilon f_\bullet $, where $f_\bullet:C_0X \to C_0Y$. Why is that? Well, $\epsilon f_\bullet (\sum a_i \sigma_i) = \epsilon (\sum a_i f_\bullet (\sigma_i) )= \sum a_i$ which is still just evaluation...